# Possible to drop down to Ubuntu in Google Chrome OS?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome-os

I've heard that Google Chrome OS is built upon Ubuntu.

Does this mean it's possible to drop down to Ubuntu shell and install native applications?

Comment: I've heard that Ubuntu is built upon baby unicorns. Does this mean... no, wait...

Comment: @bzlm: no need to be an idiot.

Comment: No need to ask Super User questions on Stack Overflow either. :)

Comment: @bzlm: sorry for that, but you are still an idiot :)

Comment: This is an even better place to ask: http://askubuntu.com (the Stack Exchange site for Ubuntu questions)

Comment: It's built on the Linux kernel, which is different than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a Cr-48 notebook today. You can enter the developer mode and get access to the shell. Unfortunately, no package manager is installed, so although it's technically a Linux, you can only run the existing programs. You either rebuild the ChromiumOS image yourself to add any program, or install Ubuntu on a spare partition.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [install packages from Arch Linux](http://reddog176-chrome.blogspot.com/2010/12/installing-nano-text-editor.html), amazingly enough. As the previous answerer mentioned, there is no package manager on the Cr-48, so you are limited in which Linux distributions you get packages from. Those have to be really simple and tar-based.